# What to look for when buying USB A/B/mini/micro to USB C adapters?

Tags: usb, cables

For personal use, I'm putting together a kind of "computer emergency" kit with cables, tools, usb keyboard, small monitor, etc. To keep the kit small, I'm trying to avoid having to get every possible combination of USB converter cable by buying only a subset of cables and getting plug adapters to fill out the rest of the possibilities. By "adapter", I mean these kinds of things:

[image]

We can assume power delivery is **not** a concern; my goal is to connect devices (e.g., disk drives, other peripherals) temporarily to Mac and Windows computers when investigating hardware problems. Example scenario: connect an (old) external hard drive enclosure having a USB 3.0 type B female port to a Mac laptop having a USB C female port, without having a dedicated USB 3.0 type B male to USB C cable on hand.  (One approach for that scenario is a cable that has USB 3.0 type B male on one end, USB 3.0 type A on the other end, plugged into an adapter that has a USB 3.0 type A female on one end and a USB C male on the other end. Other combinations would work too.)

Being a nonexpert in this area, it is not clear to me which combinations of adapters and cables *can* work, given that some USB standards have differences in things like *host* versus *device* side. If my goal is to have a way to connect any of the following to any other, **what should I look for, in terms of the properties of the connectors and cables, and the combinations that are feasible**?

- USB type A female
- USB 3.0 type A female
- USB type A male
- USB 3.0 type A male
- USB type B male
- USB 3.0 type B male
- USB 3.1 type C female
- USB 3.1 type C male
- USB mini A
- USB mini B
- USB micro B
- USB micro B super speed

An example of the minimum I can imagine is to have a single cable that has USB C on both ends, and then get two copies of small plug adapters each having USB C female on one end and every possible other type on the other end.  (So, the arrangement would be `T1-cable-T2`, where `T1` is one adapter and `T2` is another adapter.) However, it's not obvious to me whether there are combinations that can't work, and whether there are differences in the design or wiring of the adapters that need to be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

Your minimum suggestion is a good one.  USB C 3.1 can operate at the highest speed and so this is best implemented with no adaptors at all.  There are some non-standard configurations such as A to A that are used in certain circumstances even though they don’t have an ‘official’ use, but you can be sure that the one you haven’t got is the one you’ll need.